# Mediation: categorical predictor- significant indirect but non-significant total effect

Tags: mediation

I'm running a mediation model in PROCESS (Model 4) with a categorical predictor which has 3 categories. The predictor was further dichotomized using dummy coding into 2 dummy variables. The outcome is binary (yes/no). The mediator is an interval variable with a range 0-14.

I am looking at the difference between a control group (reference), inpatients (dummy variable X1) and outpatients (dummy variable X2) on risk of self-harm (yes/no), and whether it can be explained by cumulative trauma.

Here is what I get:
1) X1 (which is the difference b/w control and inpatient groups) has no relationship with the outcome (Y). Significantly predicts the mediator (M), and the M predicts the Y. The indirect effect is significant (based on the 95% CIs).

2) X2 (the difference b/w control and outpatients) has a significant effect on Y. With the M in the model, the direct effect becomes less significant. The indirect effect is significant.

I can explain the X2 case but not the X1 case. 
Specifically, what the indirect effect really means in this situation.

Looks like inpatients and control group don't differ in risk of self-harm. But the mediator (trauma) does play a role in this relationship...

there is no random assignment, the data is cross-sectional. I am aware that I can not claim causation. Just trying to understand the process of how these relationships work. 
I would appreciate any input.

Comment: It's been awhile since I last used SPSS, but has PROCESS been updated to accommodate dichotomous outcomes (it wasn't capable of this last I used it)? If not, this output may not be very meaningful.

Comment: @jsakaluk - the version that I use (Process 2.13, Model 4) can be used with binary outcomes . It runs logistic regression and provides standardized coefficients (the model incliudes age and sex as covariates+ dummy-coded IV and an interval mediator).

Comment: If that's the case, then M completely explains the difference between Inpatients vs. Controls on Y (your first significant indirect effect, without a significant direct effect), whereas M only partially (but significantly) explains the difference between Outpatients vs. Controls on Y (as the direct effect is still significant).

Comment: @jsakaluk, thank you. That's what I was thinking. And in addition to that: 1) low power; 2) suppression by another variable that is not included in the model - based on Rucker et al., 2011 http://quantpsy.org/pubs/rucker_preacher_tormala_petty_2011.pdf